# Accessing images from photo albums in ipad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad

Is it possible to access images inside the folders in albums in iPad's library through UIImagePickerController

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

Comment: with this we can access images present in library i.i in photos section.i want to access images present in album's folder

Answer (score 1):

here's the code......just create a button...n get the selected image from picker any where u want(modal or an view)
u can also access camera pics by using

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 


-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } 

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```